# How to solve 'Attribute : .......cannot be set to null' error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, script-component

I am setting 'statecode' field of entity 'quote' of CRM using script component in ssis as:

```
if(!Row.activated_IsNull)
        {
            quote.Attributes["statecode"] = Row.activated;
        }
        else
        {
            quote.Attributes["statecode"] = null;
        }
```

But I am getting following error when I run the it:

[image]

What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Dynamics CRM (aka PowerApps) statecode/statuscode is not nullable, and cannot accept the null value in DB. The pair is kind of pre-defined/pre-paired/configurable set of values that can correlate together. [Read more](https://carldesouza.com/understanding-statecode-statuscode-status-and-status-reason-in-dynamics-365/) and the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/quote?view=op-9-1&WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#BKMK_StateCode) can help you to understand it.

Either you should default it to the Initial status (for ex. "Draft" or "Active") or create your own custom picklist attribute for nullable status field.